# How do Fingerprint with rails for login on system

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, fingerprint, biometrics

I have a question. There is a gem, lib or anything in ruby or rails about fingerprint? Have a system in Java that the user puts the digital and can do login with name, email, password, and others.
Can do the same with ruby on rails? I have the hardware of biometria, but how do software, because I just have in java...

Comment: Each fingerprinting system is totally different. Which one are you trying to use? Do they have a software development kit in Java? Do they have a Ruby driver?

Comment: Just driver for Java, I don't know ruby drive of fingerprint : (

Comment: Not sure what to say here. You haven't given a lot of information to help with a solution.

Comment: I just want some that I can put my finger and can sign in my system. With the fingerprint can take my credencials and enter. Simply. For Java have this, I would know if ruby on rails have this too.

Comment: I don't know. Have you looked for a compatible library on Rubygems?

Comment: I never see some for ruby on rails, just java.

Comment: You could try to combine the two with Jruby.

Comment: Have some tutorial? I never used Jruby

Comment: [Install it and use it.](http://jruby.org) It's like Ruby but in Java, not really all that different. The big bonus is you can integrate with existing Java code more natively.